# How To Use Tesseract OCR in PHP?

Tags: php, tesseract

I am using XAMPP on my Windows.
I wanted to use Tesseract OCR in PHP

My tesseract installed in

```
C:/Program Files/Tesseract OCR/
```

And XAMPP was installed in

```
C:/xampp/
```

I am using this code to exec the Tesseract in my PHP

```
exec("tesseract test.png test.txt");
```

But it's not working...

Comment: In my case 

shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe" "E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\images\\'.$file_name.'" out');
But not work

Answer (score 3):

Your `exec` function should be

`exec("tesseract.exe test.png test.txt");`

You're missing the .exe extension on tesseract. I just made the same mistake!

Also, your tesseract should be installed on your xampp server as well.

Comment: Hey my code is 

shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe" "E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\images\\'.$file_name.'" out');

But its not work

Comment: @KrunalPandya, I haven't worked with Tesseract in over 5 years now, so I'm not quite up to speed on how it works. Have you tried running this through the shell itself and not through PHP? That will eliminate any issues with PHP and could give you any output messages that Tesseract comes up with. Good luck!

Comment: It's working but I have some problem. I want data to convert in an array format for each row and in my image, there is a 4 column.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Debes tener eng.traineddata y el tesseract.exe en la carpeta prueba#
//este codigo funciona en el servidor local
<?php 
$imagen = file_get_contents('http://e-consultaruc.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-
itmrconsruc/captcha?accion=image');
file_put_contents('C:\AppServ\www\Sitio AAA\Prueba\foto.jpg', $imagen);
exec("tesseract.exe foto.jpg mitexto2.txt");
?>
<form action="obtener_imagen_captcha.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice tutorial here. 
https://chillyfacts.com/convert-image-to-text-optical-character-recognition-ocr-using-php/

This code here works for me:

```
    <?php
    shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract" "example_image.PNG" out');
    ?>
```

(Part 1) Here is the explanation to The first part of this code defines the directory where Tesseract is installed. So change the directory based on your computer file.

```
(Part 1)
"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract"
```

(Part 2) The second part of the code defines the directory for the image file. So in my case the php file with the `shell_exec()` function is the same directory where I have the image file `example_image.PNG`. If you have a different directory for your image it can be defined like this `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\images\\example_image.PNG`

```
(Part 2)
"example_image.PNG"
```

(Part 3)
The third part defines the filename for the output text file.

```
(Part 3)
out
```

Answer (score 0):

The reply is too late. But hopefully, help the others.Code is:

```
shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract" "F:\\WebApp5\\htdocs\\imgtotext\\images\\'.$file_name.'" out');
```

Here shell_exec('"Your tesseract file location" "your image location" file_name'). Thanks.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Before check please

run cmd administrator

```
tesseract
```

If the information is displayed

copy your test.png to desktop and run this code

```
cd %userprofile%\desktop
tesseract test.png test
```